# For $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, how can you manipulate this function's graph to yield this function's graph: $\sqrt{2x+1}$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

The graph of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is the original function. Through transformation, the $f(x)$ function is changed to become $\sqrt{2x+1}$. Why can we not do this:

1. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$              $\implies$ Graph is straightforward
2. $g(x) = f(x+1) = \sqrt{x+1}$   $\implies$ Graph is $\sqrt{x}$ shifted 1 to the left
3. $k(x) = g(2x) = \sqrt{2x+1}$   $\implies$ Graph is $\sqrt{x+1}$ compressed by factor of 2

But the proper graph of $\sqrt{2x+1}$ is a graph of $\sqrt{x}$ starting at point $(-\frac{1}{2}, 0)$. Why does my method not work? How could you then manipulate the graph of $\sqrt{x}$ to give the proper graph?

Comment: Swap steps 2 and 3 in your method. You must scale first before you shift!

Answer (score 1):

Your steps 2 and 3 are mixed up! The correct process is:

1. Sketch $f(x)= \sqrt{x}.$
2. Sketch $g(x)=f(2x)=\sqrt{2x}.$
3. Sketch $h(x)=g(x+1/2)=\sqrt{2x+1}.$

You will see that this method gives you the desired starting point of $\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right)$, since step 2 compresses by a factor of 2, and step 3 shifts the graph to the left by half a unit.

Comment: Ok. I understand what you did. But why can you not substitute (x+1) first in your Step 2 and then substitute 2x for Step 3? Is stretching/compression or rather, multiplication, always done first in a series of transformations?

Comment: Is that the correct way to go about it--to apply multiplicative transformations first, before doing any other transformations? But if so, why does order of transformation matter?